# Usage of Wildcards in AHK Loop Files and Folders

Tags: autohotkey

I am searching for a more explicit way to define a loop in files in folders. Take the loop below for an example. It's looking for `text*.txt` files. But I'd like to define a more specific wild card search that can find files such as `text1.txt`, `textA.txt`, but NOT `text1 - COPY.txt`

I'm not familiar with the AHK wildcard syntax but perhaps what I'm looking for can be explained using regex, I'm looking for `"text.\.txt"` ... where the first `.` (dot) matches any single character (as opposed to `"text.*\.txt"` where the dot asterisk is anything)

```
loop, % C:\Users\username\Downloads\text*.txt
  {
    ; do arbitrary tasks in loop.
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming `loop, % C:\Users\username\Downloads\text*.txt` was a *typo*, since that won't actually even compile. You'll need quotes around a string in an expression, but I'm sure you know that already.

Though, you may not be aware that you're using the deprecated legacy file loop.
Switch over to the [modern file loop](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/LoopFile.htm#new).

And about your question, I'd say that the best you can do is just filtering further while in the loop. Then you can also filter with whatever method you wish.
Here's an example with the regex you mentioned:

```
Loop, Files, % "C:\Users\username\Downloads\text*.txt"
    if (A_LoopFileName ~= "text.\.txt")
        MsgBox, % "This file passed the additional filter: " A_LoopFileName
```

And if you're not familiar with the `~=` operator in AHK, it's a [shorthand for `RegExMatch()`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#regex).